# Blazor and EF Core: how to update a complex object

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying some basic operations with Blazor WebAssembly and EF.

Suppose I have the following code (this is a simplified version of a more complex scenario):

```
var id = 1;

var q = await _db.Orders
    .Include(x => x.Customer)
    .Include(x => x.OrdersCarriers)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Carrier)
    .Include(x => x.OrdersProducts)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Product)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Producer)
    .Where(x => x.orderId == id)
    .Select(x => x).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
                        
var op = new OrderProduct()
{
    OrderId = id,
    Product = new Product() { ProducerId = 1, Description = "New Product" }
};
q.OrdersProducts.Add(op);

_db.Orders.Update(q);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

This code works fine, a new entry in Products table is created with description "New Product" and a new row in in OrdersProducts is also added.

Now I want to break this operation in three steps: order selection is done in the controller and result is passed to client app, then the client app edits the order and finally passes the order back to controller for db update operations.

I wrote this code:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // [...]
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    // [...]
}
```

**OrdersController.cs**

```
private readonly DataContext _db;

public OrdersController(DataContext db)
{
    _db = db;
}

[HttpGet("getorder/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrder(int id)
{    
    var q = await _db.Orders
        .Include(x => x.Customer)
        .Include(x => x.OrdersCarriers)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Carrier)
        .Include(x => x.OrdersProducts)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Product)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Producer)
        .Where(x => x.orderId == id)
        .Select(x => x).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
                            
    if (q == null)
        return BadRequest();
    else
        return Ok(q);
}

[HttpPut("saveorder")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveOrder(Order order)
{
    _db.Orders.Update(order);
    _db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(true);
}
```

**OrdersService.razor**

```
public class OrdersService : IOrdersService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _http;

    public OrdersService(HttpClient http)
    {
        _http = http;
    }

    public async Task<Order> GetOrder(int id)
    {
        var r = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<Order>($"api/Orders/getorder/{id}");
        return r;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SaveOrder(Order order)
    {
        var r = await _http.PutAsJsonAsync<Order>("api/Orders/saveorder", order);
        return bool.Parse(await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }

}
```

**EditPage.razor**

```
// [...]
private async void EditOrder()
{
    var op = new OrderProduct()
    {
        OrderId = order.OrderId,
        ProductId = 7
    };
    order.OrdersProducts.Add(op);


    await OrdersService.SaveOrder(order);
}
```

This code throws the following exception in `SaveOrder` method (in the controller):

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type
> 'OrderCarrier' cannot be tracked because another instance with the
> same key value for {'OrderId', 'CarrierId'} is already being tracked.
> When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance
> with a given key value is attached. Consider using
> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
> conflicting key values.

If I exclude these lines from the query:

```
.Include(x => x.OrdersCarriers)
.ThenInclude(x => x.Carrier)
```

The exception becomes:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type
> 'Producer' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same
> key value for {'ProducerId'} is already being tracked. When attaching
> existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given
> key value is attached. Consider using
> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
> conflicting key values.

If I exclude this line from the query:

```
.ThenInclude(x => x.Producer)
```

Then no exception is thrown, but my changes are not saved anyway.

My actual object is more complex than the one I described above, so the ability to make all my changes persistent with a few instructions would be very handy!

Comment: Just do not call `Update`. Object retrieved from database already tracked.

Comment: How you register the DbContext?   It looks like you have a Singleton. Which is bad.

Comment: In the Get action you could/should use `_db.Orders.AsNoTracking(). ...`

Comment: I updated the question to show how DbContext is registered. I also tried with ```.AsNoTracking()``` but it gives me the same exceptions.

Comment: You have to decide what you really need to update. I can' t belive that you changed all these includes. And after this update just that entity,